# Android Tutorial Database Access

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the Android Tutorial examples for SQLite3 database access at  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html.  I'm getting stuck on an error message that I can't understand:

> The constructor FeedReaderDbHelper(Context) refers to the missing type
>   Context

I don't get why the compiler complains that the type `Context` is missing or how to fix the error.  The error is reported on the line `mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(c);` of the first file.  Here are the source files:

File 1: MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sqlitetest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View v = findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
        Context c = v.getContext();
        mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

File 2: FeedReaderContract

```
package com.example.sqlitetest;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.content.*;

public final class FeedReaderContract {
       // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // give it an empty constructor.
    public FeedReaderContract() {}

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
//        ...
    }

    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
        FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
//        ... // Any other options for the CREATE command
        " )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME;

    public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

        public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
        }
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
            // to simply to discard the data and start over
            db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
            onCreate(db);
        }
        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** use `mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(this); or mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getApplicationContext());`

so your `onCreate()` should be

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(this);
    }
```

---

**2.**

use `extends SQLiteOpenHelper` this in Main class instead of in subclass so change to `public class FeedReaderContract extends SQLiteOpenHelper`

and `make constructor of FeedReaderContract` and `than pass context to constructor of FeedReaderContract`

and also all other c`ode/functionality of FeedReaderDbHelper move to FeedReaderContract`

Comment: I pasted in your changes (both of them), but the error remains the same :-(

Comment: Fixed it!  I had FeedReaderDbHelper as a subclass.  I moved it to its own class and the problem vanished